# Result of syntax in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm switching from C++ to JS.

```
//if ( condition )
{
  instruction1;
  instruction2;
}
```

In C/C++ commenting `if` before the block would simply execute the block unconditionally.

Could I use it the same way in JS? Or would it create an unnamed object which is never used?

Comment: It will just ignore that and execute it exactly like a generic **block** (like it would do with an if or whatever). Check the console in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oxhpb65m/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very quick way of testing:

```
{
    alert("foo");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4obksb0s/

Yes - it appears to run fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks! As a learner one makes so many mistakes. One is never certain if a test is proper one or not.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: If you're "new" to javascript, in my opinion, the best way you have to answer to such questions is to create a fiddle on jsfiddle and directly test either syntax or really any generic language doubt you have and check the javascript console (any browser has it), it's the fastest way to understand what you can and you can't do :P. If you don't see any error (remember to clear the console log everytime) then you probably can feel **safe** in that way ;).

Comment: @briosheje The problem is, how should you know, if what you've tested is not biased to some assumptions which are false? the ´ {}´ block could have different meanings in different contexts. (Actually this answer was not as deep as I wished). My first assumption "JS has C-like syntax" failed already many times on my short JS-learning path.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz: If you take a fast look at unary javascript operators and eventually at javascript ECMA5's anonymous functions you will pretty much find out that javascript has a c-like syntax, but for many other things it has barely nothing to do with it, it's just matter of getting used to it :P